# ListView and SearchView bug

Tags: java, android

So I have a ListView in which I have filled random values. I also have a SearchView above the ListView. Whenever I click the SearchView, the Listview goes up. I do not want the Listview to be moved from its place. I am attaching two images for reference.

[image]

This is when the searchview is not active

[image]

This is when the searchview is active

Edit:: On emulator it works fine

CODE::`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="7dp"

        android:src="@drawable/navigation_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_sans_bold"
        android:text="Library"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="39sp" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="649dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:divider="@null" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_background"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:queryHint="Search music"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/search" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

`
NOTE: I HAVE A CUSTOM LISTVIEW IN WHICH I AM FILLING VALUES. I HAVE NOT IMPLEMENTED SEARCHVIEW CODE TILL NOW.

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to diagnose any problems with it.

Comment: @HenryTwist I will post the code after 4hr. I am working now. Thanks

Comment: @HenryTwist I have posted code. Please check. I have not implemented searchview code till now. I will implement it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these lines of code solved the problem.
Hope this may help some coder.
`android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:isScrollContainer="false"`